# "searchbox" variable cannot be resolved error

Tags: java

I am running the following code and getting an error saying "searchbox cannot be resolved. How do I resolve this issue? Please help. I am unable to find out the reason why I getting this error. Thanks in advance :)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class DataDriven_Ex {

     public static void main(String[] args) { 

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.get("http://www.amazon.in");

    WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));
     }

     @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        File file = new File("F://Selenium excel//DataDriven.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
        XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");


        int rowcount = sh.getLastRowNum();

        for (int i = 0; i<=rowcount;i++)
        {

            String keyword = sh.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();


            searchbox.sendKeys(keyword);

            searchbox.submit();      

        }

    }       

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your searchbox variable is **declared locally** to the static method main(). The searchbox is not visible from method test(). This is the problem in the code.

Solution: move searchbox declaration from method to class. And add static modifier to the variable declaration. See the code below.

```
static WebElement searchbox;

public static void main(String[] args)
{ 

    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.amazon.in");

    searchbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `searchbox` object is local to main method, you can not access local variables out side their block. That is why you are having this issue.

**Solution:** Move the `searchbox` to outside main, make it a class level static variable, then access it.

```
public class DataDriven_Ex {
    static WebElement searchbox;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.amazon.in");
        searchbox = driver.findElement(By
                .xpath("//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));

    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        File file = new File("F://Selenium excel//DataDriven.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
        XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

        int rowcount = sh.getLastRowNum();

        for (int i = 0; i <= rowcount; i++) {

            String keyword = sh.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

            searchbox.sendKeys(keyword);

            searchbox.submit();

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare

```
 static WebElement searchbox;
```

before main method - as below

```
static WebElement searchbox;
public static void main(String[] args) { 

FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("http://www.amazon.in");

searchbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

That was because your variable `searchBox` was not declared within the context of your method `test()`. If you just declare it in the `main()`, it cannot be seen from `test()`

Move this line of code:

```
WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));
```

down into your `test()` method:

```
public void test() throws Exception {
    //Move here..
    WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']"));

    File file = new File("F://Selenium excel//DataDriven.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
    XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

    //Your other codes here..
}
```

---

*While you can make `searchBox` a `static` variable, but I **do not recommend** that. Once you make it `static`, the variable will become an attribute of the `class` and not individual objects anymore.*

Comment: Ok.....just curious to know what is the disadvantage of making it a static variable

Comment: @Priyanka It is not about disadvantage, it is about relevance. We set it as static only if it is meant to be a shared property. setting it as static means you only have a single "copy" of it, and it is shared amongst all objects. You will have to careful when doing so, because a change to it will affect all other objects.